# Turn Binary Representation into Venn Diagram

Tags: r

I have a dataset that I need to turn into a Venn diagram. the data looks like this:

```
con1 con2 con3 con4 counts
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 4165
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 118107
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 428978
0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 32045
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 84489
0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 2199
0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 67245
0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 42977
1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 780948
1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 40406
1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 28988
1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 3559
1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 9802772
1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 8890
1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 6577
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 84120
```

Is there any R package can turn this format into a Venn diagram...

What I have done:

I have looked at VennDiagram package but the way that how you turn that into a Venn diagram need you already have the Venn diagram on a paper, i.e. , you need to manually fill the counts from each area into that function.

What I am looking for is a function that could turn this binary representation into a Venn diagram as it is shown above.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but here is all 2set and 3set venn diagrams with binary file names:  https://github.com/Ace-Cassidy/Venn-Diagram-Pictures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `VennCounts` and `vennDiagram` funcrions from the `limma` package - as shown at [link](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/venn.htm)

[Limma](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/limma.html) is not part of CRAN, you can type in these two commands to install limma:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("limma")
```

Here is how you load the data and draw the Venn diagram:

```
library("limma")

names(dat)[5] <- "Counts" 
dat <- as.matrix(dat)

class(dat) <- "VennCounts"
vennDiagram(dat)
```

Data should be a matrix of class `"VennCounts"` with the name Counts.

Data

```
dat <- structure(list(
    con1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    con2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    con3 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), 
    con4 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), 
    counts = c(4165L, 118107L, 428978L, 32045L, 84489L, 2199L, 67245L, 42977L, 780948L, 40406L, 28988L, 3559L, 9802772L, 8890L, 6577L, 84120L)
    ), 
    .Names = c("con1", "con2", "con3", "con4", "counts"), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L)
)
```